# crm365: How do I get a lookup type of regarding column in activity entity via web api?

Tags: dynamics-crm, lookup, webapi

When I get activity entity via web api, I can get regardingId (_regardingobjectid_value). But there is no regardingIdType in returned data.
Where do I get type of entity which lookup point to?

I call something like:

`http://<crmurl>/api/data/v8.2/activitypointers(7F0FA8DE-D818-E911-80BE-00155D14191A)?$select=*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to add in your **request header**

```
"Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=*"
```

Images below for refrence.

[image]

[image]